# Optimal Parameter for Binary Classifier

Tags: machine-learning, classification, matlab, binary-data, unbalanced-classes

If I have a binary letter classifier for the letter "I" which classifies using the sum of all pixels in a picture. The parameter that is input to the classifier decides its classification.
MATLAB CODE: 
function [ output] = simpleIClassif(input, param )
%classifier of the character I
%   input- matrix with the examples in rows
%   param- paramater of the classifier
%   output- result of the classification

sumChars = sum(input,2);

output = sumChars>param;

The data is unbalanced with 50 I's in 1000 datasets.
To find this optimal parameter what evaluation method should i use? F1 Score, Youden's Index, or something else?

Comment: Since almost surely this'll give you miserable results, what is the origin of your question? Why do you want to use such "classifier" rather then one of the standard machine learning approaches?

Comment: @Tim The task has nothing to do with classifiers.
It is to find the best method in evaluating classifiers.
Would the matthew's correlation coefficient work?

Comment: There is no single "best" method. If there were, we wouldn't have multiple methods.